# Should I use "the" in domain name ant slogan?

Tags: articles, titles

I have a slogan "Learn from the best" for my project and have bought domain name learnfrombest.com. While I'm not a native english speaker, I'm not sure it sounds good enough. I chosen domain name without article "the", but does it will be OK to use slogan also without "the"? it would be "Learn From Best"? Does it sound good? Thank you!!

Comment: Nobody can say if the domain name is right for you. The phrase itself, without the article, could also be interpreted as "the best way to learn from."

Comment: but is it correctly? Does it sounds "normal"? :) Thank you!!

Comment: The *phrase* "learn from best" is ungrammatical—so, it doesn't sound normal. But I'm in no position to judge the shorter domain name.

Comment: oh, bad news for me. LearnFromTheBest.com would be right domain name? But what about titles. As I know, it is allowed to remove The article from titles, so from domain names also? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain names do not have to be grammatically correct and often simply share words in common with their subject. For example, the website for The Weather Channel is just www.weather.com.

Comment: thank you for your answer! What is your personal opinion, I want just know or LearnFromBest.com sounds NOT STRANGE :) If it is not - I'm going to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I'd say LearnFromBest.com sounds fine, not strange at all. Actually, weirdly enough, to me, it sounds more like a legit domain name than if the "the" was in there.

Comment: Oh thank you so much for calming me down about this. I was thinking this is very good domain, but starting have doubts about that. Not it cleared out. Thank you @DerpDevil !!